# sharepoint discussion board show user photo

Tags: discussion-board

is there a way to display the user who has posted a new article on the discussion board app SharePoint 2013.  Have tried adding in with CSS and I understand that once the post is clicked on the commenters profile photo is displayed

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Discussion board list setting. Edit Created By column from Columns section. Change show field as Picture only (36*36). Save it and check in view. It will display user photo on created discussion.